# How to handle single sign out from identity server4 with frontchannel?

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, identityserver4, openid-connect

We have a solution which using multiple SPAs written in Angular and AngularJS. These application implement the oidc-client-js library and authenticate in Identity Server 4. Due to limitation of AngularJS we need to render our legacy AngularJS apps in iframe. There is one main application that allows to login through IdentityServer4 and then we can open different SPA inside that main application. This is working fine until we logout and then login on different user. On the main app and apps that are written in Angular7 the user is correct but when we enter on application that is rendered in iframe the user stays from previous session.

According to the IdentityServer docs I was trying to add
`FrontChannelLogoutUri` to notify all logged in clients and end all sessions.
But I haven't found what this logout page supposed to do.

Also I was trying to clear all grants when logging out but there is no grants to be cleared. To acheive this I used following method:

```
await _persistedGrantService.RemoveAllGrantsAsync(subjectId, clientId);
```

This method from IdentityServer returns empty list.

```
var grants = await _interaction.GetAllUserConsentsAsync();
```

I believe after FrontChannelLogoutUri is rendered the session should be ended but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

After redirect to `FrontChannelLogoutUri` probably need to clear session storage in iframe. For now this is working fine.